# WPF C# navegar desde una pagina a otra

Tags: c#, wpf

Tengo una app WPF que presenta obviamente el home que es una pagina  inicial sobre el main donde muestro el resultado de mis servicios que ofresco (servicios de fotos) pero al lado hay un menu despegable principal donde hay varias opciones y entre ellas, "configuracion" que esta en otra pagina, mi problema es que si voy a configuracion y doy al botón "guardar todo" esta tiene que redireccionarme a la pagina principal osea al home debido a que solo puedo entrar a configuracion siempre y cuando este logueado una cuenta admin y los clientes no pueden acceder a ella y una de las prevenciones para el acceso a esta configuracion es redireccionar  y no se como hacerlo! ¡ayuda!

Comment: no entiendo que relacion tiene la pagina de configuracion, con la accion de guardar, con redireccionar al home con la autenticacion admin, no queda claro

Comment: Solo quiero navegar estando de la pagina configuración a la pagina principal jajajaja

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para navegar en wpf tienes que usar el servicio de `NavigationService`

[Información general sobre navegación](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/framework/wpf/app-development/navigation-overview)

```
    void hyperlink_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        PageWithNonDefaultConstructor page = new PageWithNonDefaultConstructor("Hello!");

        this.NavigationService.Navigate(page);
    }
```

instancias la pagina y navegas a esta al presionar el link o boton